# Java Google App Engine Datastore: 'IN' operator available on JDO query filters, as with Python?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

[This page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queriesandindexes.html) describes an 'IN' operator that can be used in GAE Datastore to compare a field against a list of possible matches, not just a single value:

However this is for Python. In Java (App Engine 1.2.5), trying

```
query.setFilter("someField IN param");
```

on my javax.jdo.query fires a JDOUserException 'Portion of expression could not be parsed: IN param'.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: Which is invalid JDOQL. Suggest you read the JDO spec, or GAE/J docs for query syntax ... particularly "contains()" as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python version of `IN` is actually implemented in application-level code (which you can examine since it's part of the open-sourced App Engine SDK): essentially, a query with an `IN` like yours becomes N queries with `==` (where N == len(param)) and the results of those N queries are merged back as the overall result.

While it's arguably convenient to have this functionality as part of Google-supplied source code, there's really no added value beyond this convenience, and in particular there is no performance advantage wrt just doing it in your own code. So, I'm not surprised that this minor tweak was (at least so far) not added to the Java version...

Answer (score 2):

To use the IN operator, I use this:

```
List<Site> query(List<String> searchTerms)
{
    javax.jdo.Query q = pm.newQuery(Site.class);
    q.setFilter("param.contains(siteField)");
    q.declareParameters("java.util.Collection param");
    return (List<Site>)q.execute(searchTerms);
}
```